# How can I clear a UISession?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rap

From this [link](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/02/04/rap-2-0-countdown-25/) I saw that `For every instance of a RAP UI, a separate UISession is created. That means that when a user accesses an entry point, that’s a new UISession. When the user reloads the page in the browser, that’s also a new UISession.`

And in my application when the browser is refreshed (usually by hitting F5 or close browser and open again) and from MAT (Memory Analyzer Tool) report I see that something call UISessionImpl is created as much as the time browser refreshed. That means new UISession is created but the old sessions is still there.

So my question is "How can I clear session every time the browser refresh?".

**EDIT**

My code:

```
RWT.getUISession(myDisplay).exec(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    RWT.getRequest().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(1);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/FAQ#How_do_I_get_notified_when_the_browser_window.2Ftab_is_closed.3F
"In most recent browsers, the UI session is automatically destroyed when the client's browser window/tab is closed. For older browsers, the HTTP session timeout is used to detect whether the user has left the application."
"Note that when using the RAP launcher, by default a HTTP session never expires. To change the timeout value, adjust the setting on the "Main" tab."

The link you refere to writes about RAP 2.0, maybe you need to update to the latest version 2.3.

You can reduce session timeout value like this:

```
RWT.getRequest().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(...);
```

To clear the session on refresh, maybe you can do:

```
RWT.getRequest().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(0);
```

Comment: Your answer is about HTTPSession but my problem is UISession.

Comment: As far as I know the UISession is hooked to the HTTPSession, destroy the HTTPSession destroys the UISession.

Comment: I tried but it's not work. Session still alive. Added my code.

Comment: Where are you executing this code? It should be at an initialization point. Are you starting your application from eclipse (with RAP launcher)?
"Note that when using the RAP launcher, by default a HTTP session never expires. To change the timeout value, adjust the setting on the "Main" tab."

Comment: This code calls from createUI() method inside ApplicationEntryPoint class.

Comment: How about my other question?

Comment: Yes. I'm using eclipse Kepler with RAP launcher.

Comment: Ok then there should be a timeout value on the "Main" tab, maybe that helps